# How to get output of sql queries in FitNesse + DbFit?

Tags: fitnesse, dbfit

I am trying to get sql query output in DBfit using  i.e. `!|Execute|select * from abc|` but don't know how it will display in DBfit.

Answer (score 7):

I think that you are looking for the `Inspect Query` table (you can find reference docs about it [here](http://dbfit.github.com/dbfit/docs/reference.html#inspect)).

`!|Inspect Query|select * from abc|`

When executed, this will print the resultset of the query.

Comment: this is exactly it, Inspect Query prints out a result set :)

Answer (score 4):

First, the execute fixture is typically used for actions that do not return data, e.g.:

```
!|Execute|insert into tablename values (…)|
```

or

```
!|Execute|update tablename st... where...|
```

However, even some non-data actions have more specific commands. The above update can be done with, for example, with:

```
!|Update|tablename               |
|field_to_change=|field_to_select|
|new value       |matching value |
```

For returning data, use the query fixture

```
!|query|select Id, BatchNum from tablename|
|Id    |BatchNum?                         |
|1     |>>Bat1                            |
|2     |<<Bat1                            |
```

As shown, just put your field names in the row below the fixture, then your data rows below that.